# How to route only subnet in OpenVPN and not internet traffic

Tags: networking, openvpn

This is my OpenVPN server config:

```
local 192.168.15.231
port 11194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

And this is my client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 187.85.170.184 11194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
...
</ca>
<cert>
...
</cert>
<key>
....
</key>
<tls-crypt>
...
</tls-crypt>
```

I need that the client, when connected to the VPN and do stuffs like browsing in internet it keeps the traffic over his local network.

Only when it access resources from `192.168.15.x` it'll use the vpn.

I already tried this https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway but doesn't works.

What is wrong in my configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Removing this from server config:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Adding this:

```
push "route 192.168.15.0 255.255.255.0"
```

And removing also this from the client config:

```
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
```